# SCPI Ctrl+C alternative

Tags: cmd

I am using SCPI for some measurements. If I work from cmd, pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> would terminate the connection. Now I am trying to send the commands not by typing directly in cmd, but by sending with a file. How to send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as well inside the file?

Comment: How is CMD involved? Are you redirecting an `echo` to a COM port? If not, what exactly are you running from CMD?

Comment: Ctrl+C is implemented in the attached console (conhost.exe), not CMD. The console has an input thread with a message loop that gets keyboard input like any other Windows program. It processes keyboard input into `KEY_EVENT` records that are read via a client's `StandardInput` handle, either as a stream (e.g. `ReadConsole` or `ReadFile`) or as individual records. By default it handles Ctrl+C by broadcasting a `CTRL_C_EVENT` to all processes attached to the console, i.e. injecting a control thread in the process, which, if Ctrl+C is enabled, calls the registered control handler functions.